# run multiple instances of neo4j v3.1.1

Tags: neo4j, ports

I need to store different datasets on neo4j. I don't want to use the same instance with labels as this might affect the performance of the algorithms that I want to run. Therefore I am looking into ways of running multiple instances of neo4j on different ports.

I am having some difficulties in doing so as the guidelines found online are for other versions of neo4j. Can somebody help me please?

I am running neo4j 3.1.1 on Windows 10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the zip distribution, provide multiple config files and the NEO4J_CONF environment variable pointing to those.

you have to adapt:

- database location
- http(s) port
- bolt port

Comment: im using the community version as I need this for my studies

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker:

```
docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    neo4j:3.0
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/

Comment: is there any other way? I need to run this on windows server 2012 and its giving me some problems